# webrtc - get webcam's aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to learn how to develop webRTC applications and I would like to know whether you can get a camera's aspect ratio... (I don't know if it helps, but I'm using webrtc.io, but -if it's better- I could stop using it)

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings#Properties_of_video_tracks), you can get the current video stream's `aspectRatio` from `MediaTrackSettings` by calling:

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().aspectRatio
```

Comment: The result is `undefined` in Firefox Developer Edition but it works in Chrome.

Comment: Seems like even though `aspectRatio` is not available in Safari (IOS) in my case, width and height are available everywhere, so I can get the same result by dividing width by height - `const aspectRatio = settings.width / settings.height`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are accessing the camera through a `<video>`-element, you should use [the `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/HTMLVideoElement) to calculate the aspect ratio. These values reflect the actual dimensions of the source mediastream and can differ from the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<video>` element as rendered on the page.

This approach seems to work well in Chrome and Firefox Nightly.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the best assumption is square pixels, and thus width/height is a good approximation.

There's discussion in the Media Capture Task Force about capabilities, but the actual aspect ratio isn't available currently IIRC.

You should ask on the public-media-capture list at w3.org