# Is there a way to get aspect ratio of the webcam in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webcam, mediadevices, browser-api

I'm trying to get the aspect ratio of the webcam using javascript.
As per this documentation, it's not working for firefox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/aspectRatio

As Per it says, and I tried it's working in chrome perfectly well and not working in firefox, it gives undefined for aspect ratio in firefox.

But I have seen that this site - https://webcamtests.com/
Somehow able to detect the aspect ratio of the webcam?

Is there any workaround to get the aspect ratio for firefox?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021159/webrtc-get-webcams-aspect-ratio/58160251

Comment: As it says in the comments, It says Its not working for firefox
"The result is undefined in Firefox Developer Edition but it works in Chrome."